# How to solve $5=a+2b$, $3=c+2d$ with $ad-bc = \pm 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In 'theory', if we choose a point $(x',y')$ on fundamental lattice it can be 'achieved' by any point $(x,y)$ if $ad-bc = \pm 1$ in the system of equations $x'=ax+by$ and $y'=cx+dy$. But how in practice it is done? That is:

1- solving two equations with four unknowns $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ with one constraint $ad-bc \pm 1$ doesn't give a unique matrix?

2- which integers in $5=a.1+b.2$, $3=c.1+d.2$ hold such that $ad-bc = \pm 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the two equations individually first.

$a+2b=5$ gives $a=2n+1,\ b=2-n.$

$c+2d=3$ gives $c=2m+1,\ d=1-n.$

Now $ad-bc= 3n-5m -1,$ so you have two more linear equations to solve.  In each case, you solve them in terms of a parameter $s$ and then substitute back in to the solutions above.

**EDIT**

I'm assuming you know how to solve a linear diophantine equation in $2$ unknowns.  If you don't, make a comment, and I'll explain.

Comment: $d=1-m$ ........